# Only one item is added in state when adding multiple with multiple setState calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

For learning purposes, I'm creating an e-shop, but I got stuck with `localStorage`, `useEffect`, and React context. Basically, I have a product catalog with a `button` for every item there that should add a product to the cart.

It also creates an object in `localStorage` with that item's id and amount, which you select when adding the product to the cart.

My context file:

```
 import * as React from 'react';

 const CartContext = React.createContext();

 export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = React.useState([]);

 const handleAddtoCart = React.useCallback((product) => {
   setCartProducts([...cartProducts, product]);
   localStorage.setItem('cartProductsObj', JSON.stringify([...cartProducts, product]));
 }, [cartProducts]);

 const cartContextValue = React.useMemo(() => ({
   cartProducts,
   addToCart: handleAddtoCart, // addToCart is added to the button which adds the product to the cart

 }), [cartProducts, handleAddtoCart]);

 return (
   <CartContext.Provider value={cartContextValue}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
   );
 };

export default CartContext;
```

When multiple products are added, then they're correctly displayed in `localStorage`. I tried to log the `cartProducts` in the console after adding multiple, but then only the most recent one is logged, even though there are multiple in `localStorage`.

My component where I'm facing the issue:

```
const CartProduct = () => {
  const { cartProducts: cartProductsData } = React.useContext(CartContext);
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const productsObj = localStorage.getItem('cartProductsObj');
      const retrievedProducts = JSON.parse(productsObj);

      if (productsObj) {
        Object.values(retrievedProducts).forEach(async (x) => {
          const fetchedProduct = await ProductService.fetchProductById(x.id);
          setCartProducts([...cartProducts, fetchedProduct]);
        });
      }
    }
  )();
 }, []);

 console.log('cartProducts', cartProducts);

 return (
   <>
    <pre>
      {JSON.stringify(cartProductsData, null, 4)}
    </pre>
   </>
  );
 };

 export default CartProduct;
```

My service file with `fetchProductById` function:

```
const domain = 'http://localhost:8000';
const databaseCollection = 'api/products';
const relationsParams = 'joinBy=categoryId&joinBy=typeId';

const fetchProductById = async (id) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${domain}/${databaseCollection}/${id}?${relationsParams}`);
  const product = await response.json();

  return product;
};

const ProductService = {
  fetchProductById,
};

export default ProductService;
```

As of now I just want to see all the products that I added to the cart in the console, but I can only see the most recent one. Can anyone see my mistake? Or maybe there's something that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks bad:

```
Object.values(retrievedProducts).forEach(async (x) => {
  const fetchedProduct = await ProductService.fetchProductById(x.id);
  setCartProducts([...cartProducts, fetchedProduct]);
});
```

You run a loop, but `cartProducts` has the same value in every iteration

Either do this:

```
Object.values(retrievedProducts).forEach(async (x) => {
  const fetchedProduct = await ProductService.fetchProductById(x.id);
  setCartProducts(cartProducts => [...cartProducts, fetchedProduct]);
});
```

Or this:

```
const values = Promise.all(Object.values(retrievedProducts).map(x => ProductService.fetchProductById(x.id)));
setCartProducts(values)
```

The last is better because it makes less state updates

Answer (score 0):

Print the `cartProducts` inside `useEffect` to see if you see all the data

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('cartProducts', cartProducts);
}, [cartProducts]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

When you call a state setter multiple times in a loop for example like in your case, React uses what's called [Automatic Batching](https://dev.to/this-is-learning/automatic-batching-in-react-18-273h), and hence only the last call of a given state setter called multiple times apply.

## Solution

In your `useEffect` in `CartProduct` component, call `setCartProducts` giving it a function updater, like so:

```
setCartProducts(prevCartProducts => [...prevCartProducts, fetchedProduct]);
```

The function updater gets always the recent state even though React has not re-rendered. React documentation [says](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

> If the new `state` is computed using the previous `state`, you can pass a function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

Comment: but that's exactly how I called setCartProducts:

` setCartProducts([...cartProducts, fetchedProduct]);`

Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Between edits, I removed what I wanted you to use. It should be as I just edited.

Answer (score 0):

if this line its returning corrects values

```
const productsObj = localStorage.getItem('cartProductsObj');
```

then the wrong will be in the if conditional: replace with

```
(async () => {
      const productsObj = localStorage.getItem('cartProductsObj');
      const retrievedProducts = JSON.parse(productsObj);

      if (productsObj) {
       Object.values(retrievedProducts).forEach(async (x) => {
        const fetched = await ProductService.fetchProductById(x.id);
        setCartProducts(cartProducts => [...fetched, fetchedProduct]);
       });
      }
    }
```